# Get variable of another option in a selector after switch case

Tags: javascript, select, switch-statement

I'm working on a Roman Date calculator and I'm having trouble getting a variable of another option from a selector after a switch case.

So I have my variable:

```
x = "J";
```

And the switch case:

```
switch(document.getElementById('mySelector').selectedIndex) {

case 0:
    x = "J";
    break;
case 1:
    x = "K";
    break;
}
```

Now, while the option that is case 1 is selected, I want to get what the variable x is for the case 0.

If this is too vague this is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Hendrich/dkoLLwrz/6/

The problem is towards the bottom of changeDayAmnt();

Comment: ... So what's the problem?

Comment: TL;DR what's the problem with your code?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? please clarify

Comment: Put your possible values for `x` in array and get the appropriate value from the array using which ever 'case #' is appropriate as an index to the array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function so you can reuse your code:

```
function foo(index) {
  var y = 'J';

  switch(index) {

    case 0:
      y = "J";
      break;
    case 1:
      y = foo(0);
      //do something else
      break;
    }

  return y;
}

x = foo(document.getElementById('mySelector').selectedIndex);
```

Haven't tested it, just to give you an idea where to go.

Hope this helps :)

Edit:

Or, as @DavidTansey suggested use arrays:

```
var foo = [
    {
        mName: "Mart.",
        ides: 15,
        nones: 7
    }, 
    {
        mName: "Mai.",
        ides: 15,
        nones: 7
    },
    //...
    {
        mName: "Ian.",
        ides: 13,
        nones: 5
    }
    //...
}];

mName = foo[index].mName;
ides = foo[index].ides;
nones = foo[index].nones;
```